# If $S_{100} - k + k² = 7500$ and $S_{100}$ it is the sum of $100$ consecutive positive integers, then what it is the value o k?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation

$k$ must be one of the 100 consecutive integers.

I know the answers are $50$ and $26$.

But I got stuck into getting these numbers.

Here is what I tried:

$S_{100} = \frac{(n+n+99)\times100}{2} \implies S_{100} - k + k² = 7500 \implies \frac{(n+n+99)\times100}{2} + k(k-1) = 7500 \implies k(k-1) = 7500 - 50(2n+99)\implies k(k-1)= 50(51-2n) $.

It's easy to see that $n = 1 \implies k = 50$ is an answer. But how can I discover that $n = 19 \implies k = 26$?

Comment: What does "with the substitution of $k$ by $k^2$" mean?

Comment: It means that there is an integer of the sum $S_{100}$, that is interchanged by it's square. In a formula, it means $S_{100} - k + k² = 7500$

Comment: I tried to rewrite the question. See if it's better enunciated.

Comment: I corrected now, every integer from the sum must be positive.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe : $75\cdot 74 = 50(111)$, which is exactly the final equality with the indicated specialization.  Both products are $5550$.  In what way do you believe the inequality in your objection follows from the Question's chain of implications?

Comment: @erictowers the OP's original question required $n\le k < n+100$, but the OP dropped that after comments from others. Specifically, $k$ was originally one of the 100 consecutive integers being added. It was removed and replaced with its square. $75$ is not among the 100 consecutive integers starting at $-30$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe : Ah.  Now I understand why that inequality is relevant.  Thanks!  I observe that currently the title and the body of the question disagree on whether this constraint applies.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{i=n}^{n+99} i = \sum_{i=1}^{n+99} i - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \dbinom{n+100}{2} - \dbinom{n}{2} = \dfrac{(n+100)(n+99)}{2} - \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} = \dfrac{n^2+199n+9900}{2} - \dfrac{n^2-n}{2} = \dfrac{200n+9900}{2}$$

Then you have:

$$\dfrac{200n+9900}{2}+k^2-k = 7500$$

Multiplying out:

$$k^2-k+100n-2550 = 0$$

$$k = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{10201-400n}}{2}$$

So, $10201-400n$ must be an odd perfect square.

You can add the numbers $1$ through $100$ and $k=50$.

Or you can have the numbers $19$ through $118$ and $k=26$

Comment: How did you discover the values of $n$ that makes $10201 - 400n$ an odd perfect square?  Testing it's the only option?

Comment: That's how I did it. I don't know if that's the only option.

Comment: One thought I had was $10201-400n=(a-b)^2$ so try $ab=200n, a^2+b^2=10201$ but that did not lead to anything fruitful, unfortunately. The only possible choices for the $a,b$ that ensure $a^2+b^2$ is odd are $(1,200n),(200,n),(5,40n),(40,5n),(8,25n),(25,8n)$ if we assume $n$ cannot be factored, but none of these choices lead to either of the solutions. So, we can conclude $ab\neq 200n$ and I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: The book answer says that for $2 \cdot 5² \cdot (51-2n)$ to be the product of two consecutive integers, then $n = 1$ and $n = 19$.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I don't get how he inferred that. Did he use some natural numbers property? Or do you think he just tested values for $n$ until he found the possible values?

Comment: If you have two consecutive integers, one is even and one is odd. $51-2n$ is always odd for all $n$. $2\cdot 5^2$ is always even. But, what if you move the 2 to become a product with $51-2n$?. Then, you have $5^2$ and $2(51-2n)$. So, you need $2(51-2n) \in \{24,26\}$ (to be one away from $25$). Since $51-2n$ is odd, it must be $26$. So, $2(51-2n)=26 \Longrightarrow n=19$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $$k^2-k = 50(51-2n)$$

Then we must have $k^2-k \equiv 0 \pmod{50}$.

We split this up into $k^2-k \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $k^2-k \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$.

\begin{align}
   k^2-k &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
   k(k-1) &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
   k &\equiv 0, 1 \pmod {25}
\end{align}

Similarly, $k \equiv 0,1 \pmod 2$.

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
   & \pmod{2} & \pmod{25} \\
\hline
   25 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 \\
\hline
  25 & 1 & 0 \\
  26 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Hence, if $k \equiv x \pmod 2$ and $k \equiv y \pmod{25}$, Then 
$k \equiv 25x + 26y \pmod {50}$.

\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
   x \pmod 2 & y \pmod{25} & k \pmod{50} & \dfrac{k(k-1)}{50} & n \\
\hline
  0 & 0 &  0  &  0 & *\\
  \color{red}0 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}{26}  & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{19}\\
  1 & 0 & 25  & 12 & *\\
  1 & 1 &  1  &  0 & *\\
\hline
\end{array}